# iOS-Obj C How to change a object view maintaining constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, size-classes

I'm using Autolayout and Size classes for my project.

Now, I've to transform a UIImageView into View. But is there a way to do it without losing all previous constraints for UIImageView?

Comment: `UIImageView` is a view, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Joe I guess, he is trying to switch UIImageView for UIView in the Interface Builder without having to redo all the constarints

Comment: you can edit the `xib` file directly, if you dare...